# AutoComplete TextBox doesn't suggest nor append

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

This code is how I'm supposed to enable the AutoComplete option of a TextBox

```
private void SaveCustomerForm_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    col.AddRange(new string[]
                        {
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
                        });
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}
```

This is even how it says to do it in Microsoft docs, but when I type **Janu**, **Octobe** or anything else, no suggestions, no appends

And I've changed the order of these lines in different combinations!

I've also put this in the constructer of my form as some people suggested (even though it's the same), but nothing happend

What's wrong here?

Comment: For me, it works as expected. So there is something else not showed here. Are you sure that the event handler is correctly binded to the Load event? (Check setting a breakpoint in the first line) Can you please show the code that call the form containing the textbox?

Comment: Wrong TextBox? -- Why do you have `[...]_Load_1`? Did you subscribe to event twice? If you set a breakpoint there, is that code executed? -- Note that you can use any collection (e.g., `List<string>`) then write `textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange([Collection].ToArray());`

Comment: Thank you. yeah it's probably the wrong Loaded event (Doy...). I'll check it when I get to work on my computer